# Choose correct field based on other field in sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm searching for a solution where I can get results based on a field value directly in my sql statement.

For example if I have the following structure:

```
calculated_result     result_one     result_two     result_three
1                     2.50           3.40           2.90
2                     1.90           2.00           3.90
1                     1.30           2.23           1.50
```

Then I want to make a search, where it should return all results where calculated_result is 1 and result_one is higher that 2.30 and smaller or equal to 2.65.

The problem is, that I don't know how to only return rows that fits into the search the user is making.

calculated_result = 1 should check for result_one is bigger and smaller than the rows content 
calculated_result = 2 should check for result_two is bigger and smaller than the rows content
etc

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Give to us the SQL statement that you use right now... We don't make homework

Comment: Have you tried using `CASE`?

Comment: The problem is, that I don't have any idea how to do this. Anyone that can give me some hints or just help instead of that kind of comments? :-)

Comment: @njk no, I'll try that! Anyone else that have any ideas?

Comment: if you're getting the calculations in your SQL you can try using the HAVING clause. I can't tell if the table in your question is the result of your statement w/o filters, or if thats the table you're selecting data from...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  *
from    myTable
where   (calculated_result = 1 and result_one between 2.30 and 2.650)
or      (calculated_result = 2 and result_two between 2.30 and 2.650)
or      (calculated_result = 3 and result_three between 2.30 and 2.650)
```

or, if you wanted to use `case`

```
select  *
from    myTable
where   case 
          when calculated_result = 1 then result_one 
          when calculated_result = 2 then result_two
          when calculated_result = 3 then result_three
        end between 2.30 and 2.650
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [`CASE` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html).

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE (CASE
  WHEN calculated_result = 1 THEN result_one
  WHEN calculated_result = 2 THEN result_two
END) > 2.3
AND (CASE
  WHEN calculated_result = 1 THEN result_one
  WHEN calculated_result = 2 THEN result_two
END) <= 2.65
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
       * 
FROM 
       table_name 
WHERE 
       calculated_result = 1 AND
       result_one > 2.30 AND
       result_one <= 2.65
```

Comment: This misses the "choose [correct] field" bit. The question is a bit hard to decipher.

Answer (score 0):

Another:

```
select  *
from    myTable
where   calculated_result in (1, 2, 3) and 
(result_one between 2.30 and 2.650 or result_two between 2.30 and 2.650
or result_three between 2.30 and 2.650)
;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af6d5/5)

Comment: @pst thanks for pointing that out `:)`  BTW [Demo returns nothing for any of the queries here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af6d5/5)